# Create a constraint in a field depending of another field

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

i have a table T1 with three field:

```
id integer
Vocation integer : VOCATION = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4or 5
TYPE integer     : TYPE = 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8
```

Type depend of VOCATION. Example:

- if VOCATION = 1,  TYPE should be = 2 or 3 or 4 or 6
- if VOCATION = 2,  TYPE should be = 4 or 5, etc.

I work with sqlserver2008

I would create a constraint in TYPE that force the value of constraint to be, for example, 4 or 5 if the value of VOCATION is 2, etc.

I hope for the trigger solution so I create a trigger with sql. It accepted but there is no effect in the table

This the code of trigger (sql)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tg_T1]
ON [dbo].[T1]
after INSERT, UPDATE
AS

DECLARE @VOCATION int
DECLARE @TYPE int

BEGIN
   IF @VOCATION =1 
   SET @TYPE = 2
END
```

Answer (score 1):

In a trigger, you can't just reference columns as variables. You need to use the INSERTED rowset. This represents the data that was inserted and resulted in the trigger firing. Take some time to read this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(v=sql.80).aspx

For the code, it would look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tg_T1]
ON [dbo].[T1]
after INSERT, UPDATE
AS

BEGIN
   UPDATE T1
   SET TYPE = 
     CASE 
       WHEN VOCATION = 1 THEN 2
       WHEN VOCATION = 2 THEN 3
       ...
     END
   FROM T1
   INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON T1.YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY = I.YOUR_PRIMARY_KEY
END
```

Comment: Do you think this logic would find a better home in an INSTEAD OF trigger? There is something about updating a row, then updating it again that never sat well with me :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to solve this without a trigger, using a check constraint. But you'll need to make sure you are updating both `VOCATION` and `TYPE` at the same time to avoid exceptions. That is, if `VOCATION = 2` and `TYPE = 5`, then you won't be able, for example, to update `VOCATION` with `1` without changing `TYPE` to one of the relevant values, neither you will be allowed to update `TYPE` with `6` without a corresponding change of `VOCATION`. You'll still be able to update `TYPE` without changing `VOCATION` if the constraint condition allows that.

Here's the constraint definition:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T1
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_T1_TypeVocation
  CHECK (
    VOCATION = 1 AND TYPE IN (2, 3, 4, 6)
    OR
    VOCATION = 2 AND TYPE IN (4, 5)
    OR
    … /* other conditions as necessary */
  )
```

Comment: You're welcome! Have a look at [@gbn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941281/create-a-constraint-in-a-field-depending-of-another-field/6947711#6947711)'s suggestion too. He offers a more flexible solution that will ultimately have the same effect as a check constraint. It's slightly more complex to set up but easier to maintain. In any event, once you've made up your mind, please make sure to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer that has ultimately worked for you. (That's the way things work best on this site.)

Answer (score 1):

One idea:

- create another table (T1Check, say) with only VOCATION and TYPE
- primary key on T1Check is both columns
- populate T1Check with valid pairs
- create a foreign key on T1 for VOCATION and TYPE, that references T1Check

This means that data will only be allowed in T1 that matches the allowed pairs in T1Check.

More importantly, you can add new VOCATION and TYPE combination to T1Check *without* changing any code (a trigger) or CHECK constraints. It's all data driven and easier to maintain.

You can even build a GUI to let a business user defines new VOCATION/TYPE rules in T1Check.

Comment: This is definitely better than a check constraint, I like it very much! But I am beginning to think that the OP's idea of a constraint is different from what a constraint means in SQL, even though they've chosen the term to describe their intention. *Their* 'constraint', it seems, should forcedly change TYPE upon VOCATION's change, hence the idea to use a trigger (not that I agree with it...).